# useEffect keep rendering workaround

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a small problem. I want to call 4 APIs when the component start rendering so I used use effect for that so I loop my array which has 4 items and at each item I call an API, and each API save the result in selector called `filtersCount`. The problem is when filtersCount updated the loop start over. How I can prevent this without disabling the eslint ??

```js
const fetchCounts = useCallback(
  (item) => {
    if (!filtersCount[item.key]) {
      dispatch(getFilterCount({ filters: item.countFilters, key: item.key }));
    }
  },
  [dispatch, filtersCount]
);

useEffect(() => {
  exploreItemTypes.map((item) => {
    fetchCounts(item);
  });
}, [exploreItemTypes, fetchCounts]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `Ref` for this :

```
const firstRender =useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {
    if(firstRender.current == false){
      exploreItemTypes.map((item) => {
        fetchCounts(item);
       });
      firstRender.current = true 
    }

  }, [exploreItemTypes, fetchCounts]);
```

Comment: This worked, but do you think it's practical ?

Comment: yeah we I've used this in professional projects , you can probably achieve the same result using a variable declared outside of the class .

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use an empty array in your useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    exploreItemTypes.map((item) => {
      fetchCounts(item);
    });
  }, []);
```

this will stop once your iteration is over.

Comment: can't believe I didn't think of that , yeah this should be also an accepted solution , I would still add fetchCounts to the dependency array .

Comment: but this will give errors in eslint, the fetchCount must be a callback in this case and will take dependencies in the array. So, it's the same